# Get URL # hash with JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, url, hash, jstl

To get the URL hash `#` in javascript you can just do:

```
window.location.hash
```

Is there a similar simple and easy way to do it in JSTL?

Example of a URL I have: http://hatsos.com/#somehashname

If there is not a built-in easy method, how would I go about getting the URL and then parsing the hash out of it?

Comment: Isn't the [URL Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) only used on the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get the hash fragment identifier in the server side is to let the client side send a HTTP request with the value as a request parameter whenever it has changed. For example, with Ajax during the [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event. I see in your question history that you're familiar with jQuery. Here's a kickoff example:

```js
window.onhashchange = function() {
    $.get('someservlet', { 'hash', window.location.hash }, function(response) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

with

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String hash = request.getParameter("hash");
    // ...
}
```

To cover lack of IE6/7 support for `window.onhashchange`, consider [jQuery hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/).

Comment: I feared as much. The reason I need it in JSTL is so that I can add the value of the hash to the session. ${sessionScope.hash}. That way, after they initially come to a page with a hash, I can hold on to that value no matter where they go next. Be design of my client, it must be a hash... no parameters. Btw, this hash will not be changed after load time. That is the url the users come directly to. So I figured it would be available to the server, since parameters are in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a [URI Fragment id](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5), and most user agents don't even send that to the server, so you can't really get it there. JavaScript can access it because it runs on the client side.